# Git ignore is ignoring sym.llinks?

Tags: git, symbolic-link, symlink

In a laravel project I have a storage folder and inside it, I have an app folder (normally). So the full path is: `/var/www/html/myproject/storage/app`

Now I have a file server and I wish to serve the `app` folder from there. Thus I've set up an NFS server and mounted the folder into `/var/nfs/mounted/app` folder and created a link (`ln -s /var/nfs/mounted/app /var/www/html/myproject/storage/app`)

With this the project works like a charm, all the files exist. However, git keeps telling me the files are commited for deletion. No matter what I've tried to put into .gitignore, I've been ignored (badum tsss) So far, the following was tried:

- /storage/*
- **/storage
- /storage/app
- /storage/app/*

Any other ideas?

Comment: Which directory is the top level of the git repo?

Comment: /var/www/html/myproject

Comment: Just to be sure, you are trying to remove these files from the git repo?

Comment: are you trying to keep or ignore the `/var/www/html/myproject/storage/app` direcotry?

Comment: Ignore. I want to ignore everything in the `/app` directory